# XML/SWF charts example not working with cherryPy

Tags: javascript, python, cherrypy, xml-swf-charts

I am trying to use use the XML/SWF Charts library with cherrypy. I want to generate html reports with nice looking charts.

I am trying to expose one of the default examples of XML/SWF charts with cherryPy, but for some reason the javascript is not working properly with cherryPy.

I created the following python script:

```
import os.path
import os.path
import cherrypy
import os
```

class index:
    def index(self):
        return open('sample.html', 'r')
    index.exposed = True

if **name** == '**main**':
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(**file**))
    print current_dir
    print os.path.join(current_dir, 'data', 'scripts', 'AC_RunActiveContent.js')
    # Set up site-wide config first so we get a log if errors occur.
    cherrypy.config.update({'environment': 'production',
                            'log.error_file': 'site.log',
                            'log.screen': True})

```
conf = {'/js/AC_RunActiveContent.js': {'tools.staticfile.on': True,
                        'tools.staticfile.filename': os.path.join(current_dir, 'data', 'scripts', 'AC_RunActiveContent.js')}}
cherrypy.quickstart(index(), '/', config=conf)
```

I have the following directory structure:

```
D:.
+---charts_library
+---data
¦   +---css
¦   +---scripts
+---resources
    +---button_rollover
    +---chart_in_swf
    +---cursor
    +---full_screen
    +---preview_scroll
    +---scroll
```

I put the javascript file and all files needed by the library in the .\data\scripts folder. (I also tried to put these files in the root folder but that didn't work either)

the sample html file looks as follows:

```
<HTML>

<script language="javascript">AC_FL_RunContent = 0;</script>

<script language="javascript"> DetectFlashVer = 0; </script>

<script src="AC_RunActiveContent.js" language="javascript"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

<!--

var requiredMajorVersion = 9;

var requiredMinorVersion = 0;

var requiredRevision = 45;

-->

</script>

<BODY bgcolor="#FFFFFF">





<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

<!--

if (AC_FL_RunContent == 0 || DetectFlashVer == 0) {

    alert("This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js.");

} else {

    var hasRightVersion = DetectFlashVer(requiredMajorVersion, requiredMinorVersion, requiredRevision);

    if(hasRightVersion) { 

        AC_FL_RunContent(

            'codebase', 'http: //download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,45,0',

            'width', '400',

            'height', '250',

            'scale', 'noscale',

            'salign', 'TL',

            'bgcolor', '#777788',

            'wmode', 'opaque',

            'movie', 'charts',

            'src', 'charts',

            'FlashVars', 'library_path=charts_library&xml_source=sample.xml', 

            'id', 'my_chart',

            'name', 'my_chart',

            'menu', 'true',

            'allowFullScreen', 'true',

            'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',

            'quality', 'high',

            'align', 'middle',

            'pluginspage', 'http: //www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer',

            'play', 'true',

            'devicefont', 'false'

            ); 

    } else { 

        var alternateContent = 'This content requires the Adobe Flash Player. '

        + '<u><a href=http: //www.macromedia.com/go/getflash/>Get Flash</a></u>.';

        document.write(alternateContent); 

    }

}

// -->

</script>

<noscript>

    <P>This content requires JavaScript.</P>

</noscript>



</BODY>

</HTML>
```

When I double click the sample file it works fine but when I run the python script and browse to the local host address on port 8080 then a popup keeps occuring which shows the following message:

"This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js"

I think I did something wrong in my python script but I am not able to find out what I did wrong. 
Why is the javascript not working in cherryPy while it does work in the sample.html file? Did I forget something?

Answer (score 1):

```
conf = {'/js/AC_RunActiveContent.js':
    {'tools.staticfile.on': True,
     'tools.staticfile.filename':
         os.path.join(current_dir, 'data', 'scripts', 'AC_RunActiveContent.js')}}
```

And later

```
<script src="AC_RunActiveContent.js" language="javascript"></script>
```

My bet is the latter produces a 404. Try changing the line to:

```
<script src="/js/AC_RunActiveContent.js" language="javascript"></script>
```

Oh, and also your HTML could use a `<HEAD>` element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The javascript is working now. I ran into another problem. The graph is not displayed. I only see a grey box on the page. Should I also put the XML file and the SWF file in the conf?

Comment: I do not know anything Flash gadgets. Read the documentation, and try and debug it yourself. It seem plausible you need to serve the xml configuration from your server as well.